# Hibernate: "Session is closed" although never closed (manually)

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I got a really weird problem here and I absolutely cannot understand why this is happening.

The problem looks like this:

I got a class called "SmampiAccount" which holds a list of email accounts. The mapping file looks like this (shortened):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.smampi.web.model.account.SmampiAccount" table="SMAMPIACCOUNT">
            <id name="id" type="long" access="field">
                    <column name="SMAMPI_ACCOUNT_ID" />
                    <generator class="native" />
            </id>

            <bag name="mailAccounts" table="MAILACCOUNTS" lazy="false" inverse="true">
                    <key column="SMAMPI_ACCOUNT_ID"></key>
                    <one-to-many class="com.smampi.web.model.mail.account.MailAccount"/>
            </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I get instances of this class through this method:

```
public SmampiAccount loadSmampiAccount(long id) throws FailedDatabaseOperationException {

    SmampiAccount smampiAccount = null;
    Session session = null;
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        session = getSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        smampiAccount = (SmampiAccount) session.load(com.smampi.web.model.account.SmampiAccount.class, id);
        List<MailAccount> mailAccounts = smampiAccount.getMailAccounts();
        doSomething(mailAccounts);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        rollback(transaction);
        closeSession();
        throw new FailedDatabaseOperationException(e);
    } finally {
        closeSession();
    }

    return smampiAccount;
}

private Session getSession() {
    if (_session == null) {
        _session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
    if (_session.isOpen() == false) {
        _session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
    return _session;
}
```

This works fine as it is.

Now, I wanted to add a new property to the mapping file in order to save a reference to a default email account:

```
<many-to-one name="defaultMailAccount" column="DEFAULT_MAIL_ACCOUNT_ID" />
```

Now, I get an exception in the method *public SmampiAccount loadSmampiAccount(long id)* in this line:

```
List<MailAccount> mailAccounts = smampiAccount.getMailAccounts();
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getPersistenceContext(SessionImpl.java:1954)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPostLoadEventListener.onPostLoad(DefaultPostLoadEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:982)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:1026)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.smampi.web.model.account.SmampiAccount_$$_javassist_19.getMailAccounts(SmampiAccount_$$_javassist_19.java)
```

How is this possible?
The session gets not closed manually and `.commit()` isn't called yet (which would normally close the session).
It's also not possible that another method is interfering here because I create a new hibernate session for each method call which is dedicated just for this one method.

---

**Edit**

I added some debug info on the session open status:

```
session = getSession();

System.err.println(session.isOpen());
transaction = session.beginTransaction(); // 1 (true)

System.err.println(session.isOpen()); // 2 (true)
smampiAccount = (SmampiAccount) session.load(com.smampi.web.model.account.SmampiAccount.class, id);

System.err.println(session.isOpen()); // 3 (true)
List<MailAccount> mailAccounts = smampiAccount.getMailAccounts(); // Throws exception that session is closed
doSomething(mailAccounts);

System.err.println(session.isOpen()); // 4 (not called)
transaction.commit();
```

This gives me:

```
true
true
true
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
```

Comment: It looks strange. I can suggest that you inspect the state of the session before and after the call to the load method (`System.err.println(session.isOpen());` or something like that). Another question: if you manually close the session before load(), is the stack trace equivalent?

Comment: Just for the purposes of testing, does it work fine if you add `lazy="false"` to the `<many-to-one>`? Also, which verison of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: @waxwing I added some debug info to my original post. The result looks very weird to me. I also tried to add a `session.close()` BEFORE the `session.load(...)` call. That again gives me a "Session is closed" exception. If I move the `session.close()` below the `session.load(...)` call, I get `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` in this line: `List<MailAccount> mailAccounts = smampiAccount.getMailAccounts();`

Comment: @matt Adding `lazy="false"` to `<many-to-one>` had no effect. I use `Hibernate 3.6.3.Final` with `mysql-connector-java-3.0.10-stable` and `C3P0`.

Comment: Just for sanity purposes, does the stacktrace point at the exact line of `smampiAccount.getMailAccounts();` from your code sample? Are you using any other libraries in getting the Hibernate session, such as Spring, or any form of AOP? How about trying to upgrade Hibernate to a newer 3.6.x release, such as 3.6.5? Perhaps a bugfix addresses this.

Comment: @matt Yes, the stacktrace points exactly to `smampiAccount.getMailAccounts();`. I am not using Spring or any other libraries for getting the Hibernate session. There are other libraries (UI frameworks, C3P0, Javamail, Log4J...) that I use but I doubt they have something to do with that issue. I'll try the upgrade to the newest 3.6.x release. Hope that works.

Comment: @matt I just tried with "3.6.5 Final" but that didn't fix the issue :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the biggest idiot in the world.

In the setter of defaultMailAccount, I had this:

```
public void setDefaultMailAccount(MailAccount defaultMailAccount) {
    this.defaultMailAccount = defaultMailAccount;
    try {
        databasecontroller.update(this);
    } catch (FailedDatabaseOperationException e) {
        handleException(e, false, null, null);
    }
}
```

The call to `databasecontroller.update(this)` caused a cascade whenever Hibernate tried to load a persisted version from the database and that again caused the session to close.

Moving the call of `databasecontroller.update(..)` to outside the method fixed the issue.

Sorry to everyone for taking up your time and thanks for the help!

Comment: my suggestions: check out spring and read up on "separation of concerns".

Comment: I knew something was weird when I looked at that stack trace: it just got way too "far" into the code (all the way to onPostLoad) before it realized the session was closed. I was about to suggest it as a Hibernate bug. But now it all makes sense.